# How to declare global namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm new in php I want to write php code to understand namespaces, there are two file `index.php` and `autoload.php` and there is one directory that called `Lib` and there are two file in it and called them as `first.php` and `second.php` but when I run my code I see this error

```
 require(Test\Lib\firstnamespce\First.php): failed to open stream:
```

I know that I don't use namespaces in right way but I don't understand where I go wrong and how can I call my functions in classes, I read some article about namespaces and psr-0 but i confused more here is my code

First.php :

```
namespace Test\Lib\firstnamespce;
class First {
public function hello(){
echo "Hello world";
}}
```

Second.php :

```
namespace Test\Lib\secondnamespace;
class Second {
public function hello(){
echo "Hello world";

}}
```

autoload.php

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    require $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

index.php:

```
require('autoload.php');

$obj1 = new Test\Lib\firstnamespce\First();
$obj2 = new Test\Lib\secondnamespace\Second();
$obj1->hello();
$obj2->hello();
```

this is my code hierarchy :

```
Test
|
|--- Lib
|       |
|       ----First.php
|       |
|       ----Second.php
|
|----index.php
|----autoload.php
```

Comment: is it First.php or first.php?

Comment: i edit my post  First.php

Comment: All the error is saying is that your path isn't correct.

Comment: Whether your code checks out or not, on Unix `First.php` is not the same as `first.php` they stand at being case-sensitive - *Just saying*

Comment: path of file are : Test->index.php and autoload.php and Lib(-->First.php and Second.php)

Answer (score 0):

`require` works on filesystem paths. If your namespaces don't correspond to the directory/file names, you can't just that namespace directly on the filesystem. As your error message says, `Test\Lib\Firstnamespace\First.php` doesn't exist.

If I'm reading your question right, you've got the following file structure:

```
  ./index.php
  ./Autoload.php
  ./Lib/first.php
  ./Lib/second.php
```

If you wanted your require to work, then you'd have to have the following directory structure:

```
  ./Test/Lib/Firstnamespace/First.php
```

Then your require should be just `require('Lib/first.php')`. And note that many OSes (especially Unix ones) are case-sensitive. If your namespace is `First` and you look for `First.php`, then `first.php` (with a small **f**) will never be found.

Comment: I add my code hierarchy to my post. I use autoload to prevent require all of my file , but I don't know how use namespaces and how to name them

Comment: well, your filesystem doesn't have `firstnamespace` or `secondnamespace` directories. Either create those dirs and move your files into them, or remove that part of your `require` string building

Comment: I remove firstnamespce and change it to Test\Lib but I see the error again :(